# How to delete blank spaces or null Container in SliverGrid.count?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to delete the **Null Container** in **SliverGrid.count** after validated the map entries . I wish the issue arrive you . thanks in advance for you solution .

```
class myGridItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Item item;
  final EdgeInsets? margin;

  const myGridItem({
    Key? key,
    required this.item,
    this.margin,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _myGridItemState createState() => _myGridItemState();
}

class _myGridItemState extends State<myGridItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: widget.margin == null ? EdgeInsets.zero : widget.margin,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
        boxShadow: [
          BoxShadow(
            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.05),
            offset: Offset.zero,
            blurRadius: 15.0,
          )
        ],
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 37),
                  height: 180,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      image: AssetImage(widget.item.imagePath),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                // --------------------------- create favourit widget
                Positioned(
                  top: 16,
                  right: 16,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 40,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: primaryColor,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '999%',
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

                // ------------------------- discont missing
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  widget.item.name,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 13,
                    height: 1.5,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Wrap(
                  spacing: 3,
                  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          '${Item.format(widget.item.price)}',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: primaryColor,
                            height: 1.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here the creation of SliverGrid.count to display the items I tried to use SliverChildBuilderDelegate but the same issue after some Editing on it to reach the same level of SliverGrid.count .

```
class myCartItemDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myCartItemDisplayState createState() => _myCartItemDisplayState();
}

class _myCartItemDisplayState extends State<myCartItemDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: myAppBar(
        title: 'Cart',
        myBarColor: Colors.white,
        mybackWidget: HomeScreen(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigation(),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            Container(
              child: SliverGrid.count(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 0.65,
                mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                children: Fake.furniture.asMap().entries.map((f) {
                  return Container(
                    child: f.value.addToCart == 1
                        ? myGridItem(
                            item: f.value,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                              left: f.key.isEven ? 16 : 0,
                              right: f.key.isOdd ? 16 : 0,
                            ))
                        : null,
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Screen Shot of the app]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a filter before your map:

```
children: Fake.furniture.asMap().entries
  .where((f) => f.value.addToCart == 1)
  .map((f) {
    return Container(
      child: myGridItem(
        item: f.value,
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          left: f.key.isEven ? 16 : 0,
          right: f.key.isOdd ? 16 : 0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }).toList(),
```

This way you won't end up with any null entries in the first place.

Comment: The method 'filter' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'. and If I change the list to Iterable The method 'asMap' isn't defined for the type 'Iterable'. My purpose to get entries to use them with item : f.value.

Comment: My apologies, the method is named `where` in Dart, rather than `filter` as in most languages. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by add a new List it has my target entries

```
List<Item> _names = Fake.furniture.where((i) => i.addToCart == 1).toList();
```

And then :

```
_names.asMap().entries.map((f)
```

But if you have another solution with flutter give us it , thanks